# python linear regression non negative restriction on only a subset of coefficients

Tags: python, linear-regression

I know I can use lasso with positive=True, or non negative least square, but they are used to force all coefficients to be non negative. What if I only want some but not all of them to be non negative and I don't have restrictions on the rest coefficients?

Comment: One option is to do it non-automatically: Fit the model, then view the model coefficients and remove those features with negative coefficients that you want to disallow to be negative. Or, alternately, you could separate your features into those you want to `lasso` and those you don't, then fit separate models to each and [stack](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#voting-classifier) them for the final prediction

Comment: One possibility is to use a simple "brick wall" in the function, where if a condition is met - such as an individual negative coefficient - then the function returns a very large value such as 1.0E10. The large value will cause a large error. Note that if the final fitting results are at or very near the "brick wall" boundary conditions then the fitting results are not optimal. This technique has the advantage of being easy to code and quick to test.